# Ich trage gelegentlich in der Stadt einen Mantel. / Ich trage in der Stadt gelegentlich einen Mantel

Tags: word-order

Für mich klingt die zweite Variante

> Ich trage in der Stadt gelegentlich einen Mantel.

besser.

Ist die erste Variante falsch? Gibt es für die Reihenfolge eine Regel?

Comment: According to the "time-manner-place" rule the "natural" order would be *Ich trage gelegentlich einen Mantel in der Stadt* or even *Gelegentlich trage ich einen Mantel in der Stadt*. But it depends on what is being emphasized and what is "new information". So I'm looking forward to seeing answers on this one, especially the "Gibt es für die Reihenfolge eine Regel?" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So viele Fragen bezüglich Wortreihenfolge in dieser. Community... und so oft die selbe Antwort:

In der deutschen Sprache ist die Reihenfolge der Satzteile nicht sonderlich streng vorgegeben. Man nutzt die Reihenfolge zum Zweck der Betonung, und sehr viele Kombinationen sind gültig und richtig.

Im genannten Beispiel sind beide Möglichkeiten zu 100 Prozent richtig. Man KANN den Wunsch nach Betonung hier reininterpretieren, dem Sprecher ist das unter Umständen auch gar nicht bewusst:

> Ich trage gelegentlich in der Stadt einen Mantel.

Betonung auf „gelegentlich“ z.B. im Gegensatz zu „häufig“. „in der Stadt“ ist eine Ergänzung, die auch weggelassen werden könnte. Ergänzend könnte der Satz also so lauten:

> Ich trage gelegentlich in der Stadt einen Mantel, häufiger trage ich aber eine Jacke.

Das andere Beispiel:

> Ich trage in der Stadt gelegentlich einen Mantel

Hier liegt die Betonung auf „in der Stadt“... der Satz könnte -zur Verdeutlichung- so weiter gehen:

> Ich trage in der Stadt gelegentlich einen Mantel, in der freien Natur aber eher nicht.

Bei dieser -recht gewöhnlichen- Satzstellung ist das aber wie gesagt Interpretationssache und vom Sprecher nicht unbedingt so gemeint. Deutlicher wird es, wenn die Satzstellung absichtlich weiter verdreht wird. Auch diese Sätze sind zu 100% gültig, lassen aber die starke Vermutung zu, dass der Sprecher etwas besonders betonen will:

> In der Stadt trage ich gelegentlich einen Mantel.

Oder

> Gelegentlich trage ich einen Mantel in der Stadt.

Comment: Hätte man nicht besser formulieren können.

Comment: Ich frage mich das sehr oft, obwohl ich diese "Betonungsregel" kenne. Danke für deine Antwort. :)

Comment: There are many arrangements that work, and also many that don't, and if there's one thing I learned it's that while German word order is "more" flexible, you can't go around mixing things around willy-nilly. I'm thinking *Einen Mantel trage gelegentlich ich in der Stadt* would draw strange looks.